# Can a Tree have different generic types in nodes.

Tags: java, generics, tree

I have a tree that I need it to look like this

```
                 Head(T holds a string object)

                 /                        \
1st child (T MyClass object)        2nd Child (T MyOtherClass object)
```

Comment: if you choose the common superclass as generic type parameter of the tree you can. And you can just define a tree with 3 generic type parameters, one for the root, one for the left and one for the right child.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union type, a.k.a. `Either`. Here is the implementation from javaslang: http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.2/javaslang/control/Either.html

This allows you to have a `Tree<Either<A,B>>`, where nodes may be of type `A` or `B` (wrapped in `Either`). However, this works only for two types. While you can nest `Either`s (e.g. `Either<A, Either<B,C>>` for three types), this approach clearly doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggests from luk, if you're looking for a tree that's exactly as you've drawn out, you can have three generic type parameters in your class declaration.

```
class ThreeTree<U, V, W> {
    private U root;
    private V left;
    private W right;   
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help you if you want a larger, more dynamic tree. One possible option you can explore in this case is using typesafe heterogenous containers. This wouldn't be much different from having a tree of Objects and casting them to the type you want when you want to get, but you will at least be able to accomplish the basic task of putting different types into the tree.

Take a look at Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), chapter 5 for some more thoughts on generics.